# Why the llvm opt pass -instcount cannot get the instruction counts of function?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm

It is ok to use this command:

`opt -enable-new-pm=0 -instcount -stats source_IR.ll`

I will get the result like:

```
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
                          ... Statistics Collected ...
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===

 3 instcount - Number of Add insts
 2 instcount - Number of And insts
10 instcount - Number of Br insts
 1 instcount - Number of Call insts
10 instcount - Number of FAdd insts
11 instcount - Number of FDiv insts
 7 instcount - Number of FMul insts
 5 instcount - Number of ICmp insts
 2 instcount - Number of Or insts
10 instcount - Number of PHI insts
 2 instcount - Number of Ret insts
 6 instcount - Number of UIToFP insts
12 instcount - Number of basic blocks
 2 instcount - Number of non-external functions
69 instcount - Number of instructions (of all types)
```

But this is the instruction count of whole program. I want to get the instruction counts of each function in this IR.

I try the command below:

`opt -enable-new-pm=0 -instcount -stats source_IR.ll -analyze`

and I get the result:

```
Printing analysis 'Counts the various types of Instructions' for function 'main':
Printing analysis 'Counts the various types of Instructions' for function 'compute_pi_baseline':
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
                          ... Statistics Collected ...
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===

 3 instcount - Number of Add insts
 2 instcount - Number of And insts
10 instcount - Number of Br insts
 1 instcount - Number of Call insts
10 instcount - Number of FAdd insts
11 instcount - Number of FDiv insts
 7 instcount - Number of FMul insts
 5 instcount - Number of ICmp insts
 2 instcount - Number of Or insts
10 instcount - Number of PHI insts
 2 instcount - Number of Ret insts
 6 instcount - Number of UIToFP insts
12 instcount - Number of basic blocks
 2 instcount - Number of non-external functions
69 instcount - Number of instructions (of all types)
```

there is nothing after the `Printing` line.

How could I get the instruction counts of each function by using llvm command?

I prefer not to write the pass by myself first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may edit the current `instcount` pass and print the information you want after loop through each function.